# get selected index of databound list control on user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a `radiobuttonlist` that lives on a user control.  This user control lives in a repeater on a parent user control, and that user control lives on a page with a submit button.

So something like this:

```
<page>
<UserControl1>
  <Repeater>
    <UserControl2>
      <radiobuttonlist>
    </UserControl2>
  </Repeater>
</UserControl1>
<Submit button />
</page>
```

The `radiobuttonlist` is dynamically populated in the code-behind of `UserControl2`.   The problem is that when I submit the form, I need to access the `SelectedValue` of the `radiobuttonlist`, and that value is always empty.   Even if I first fire the methods that populate the `radiobuttonlist`, the `selectedvalue` of the RBL is empty.   I have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler on the RBL, but it never fires.

What do I need to do to be able to get the `SelectedValue` of the `radiobuttonlist` when I cause the parent page to postback?

Comment: Looks like the page is resetting back to normal when a postback is occurring . Because you are creating the RadioButtonList dynamically you need to populate it on every postback.. Otherwise you won't be able to access it even if it being rendered on the screen..

Comment: I am repopulating the RBL on postback, but the problem is the page doesn't "remember" which item was selected by the user.   Should that not be happening?

Comment: On further investigation, if I don't reload the repeater, Viewstate stays intact and I can get the selected value of the radiobuttonlist.   Then the problem is that UserControl1 can self-reference.  I am handling this with LoadControl(UserControl1) inside the Repeater on UserControl1.  But if I don't reload the repeater, the self-reference instances disappear.   If I do reload the repeater, I erase ViewState.   Is there a way I can have both?

Comment: Did you set EnableViewState="true" in your aspx page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.   I guess it was an order of operations issue.  The fix was to dynamically declare the event handler of the radiobuttonlist in the OnInit() of UserControl2.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) 
{ 
    base.OnInit(e);
    rblOptions.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ctrlOptions_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

Once I did that, the event started firing, even though I was re-instantiating the UserControl on postback.   Since the event was firing, I was able to obtain the Selected Index without needing to keep it in ViewState.

Answer (score 0):

When you post your datas, you re-bind your datas so you erase your selected event or values.

Try with this code in your Page_Load (Of your User Control)

```
If(! IsPostBack)
{
   //You build RadioButtonList

}
```

And persist your datas with ViewState, `EnableViewState="true"`

Comment: This isn't working either.  Stepping through the debugger, when the repeater in UserControl1 re-instantiates UserControl2, UserControl2 loses all the information in its ViewState.   Is there a way to avoid this?   I have EnableViewState="true" on UserControl2.